# Separate a column in R

Tags: r, split, multiple-columns

data.df

```
colA

2 AD
3 KF
4 GH
```

I want to split this column into two columns

```
 colA  ColB
  2     AD
  3     KF
  4     GH
```

Here's my code:

```
library(dplyr)

X1 <- data.df

ca <- as.data.frame(X1) %>% separate(X1,col=colA, into = paste("colA","colB"))
```

Error: Values not split into 1 pieces at 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pipe commands the first argument to each function will the data.frame, so try

```
library(tidyr)
dat %>% separate(colA, c("colA", "colB"))
#   colA colB
# 1    2   AD
# 2    3   KF
# 3    4   GH
```

---

#### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(colA = structure(1:3, .Label = c("2 AD", "3 KF", 
"4 GH"), class = "factor")), .Names = "colA", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

We could do this using `read.table` from `base R`.  If the 'colA' in the initial dataset is `factor` class, convert to `character`, and use `read.table`.  We can specify the column names with `col.names` argument.

```
read.table(text=as.character(dat$colA), sep='',
                      col.names=paste0('col', c('A', 'B')) )
#   colA colB
#1    2   AD
#2    3   KF
#3    4   GH
```

---

Another option is `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`.  We specify the column to be split in the `splitCols` and the `sep`.  The `direction` is 'wide' by default.

```
 library(splitstackshape)
 cSplit(dat, 'colA', ' ')
```

NOTE: "dat" from @nongkrong's post